# SQL join with last date

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I trying to join type from table by 2 columns that gives multiply rows, so this doesn't work

```
SELECT t1_id, t1.Company  t1_some_field, t2_type 
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.Company = t2.Company AND t1_id = t2_t1_id
```

**table t2**

has multiply rows for `t2.Company + t2_t1_id` with different `t2_date`

I need to join the `t2_type` with last `t2_date`

I do it like this

```
SELECT t1_id, t1.Company  t1_some_field, t2_type 
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t2
ON t1.company = t2.company 
AND t1_id = t2.t2_t1_id
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT MAX(t2_date) AS Last_Date, company, t2_t1_id
        FROM t2
        GROUP BY company, t2_t1_id) last_t2
ON t1.company = last_t2.company 
AND t1_id = last_t2.t2_t1_id

WHERE t2_date = Last_Date;
```

looks like this works, but I think should be an easier way.

Comment: Your LEFT JOIN executes as a regular INNER JOIN... (Move WHERE condition to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result.)

Comment: Your query it's OK. If you want you can transform your LEFT JOIN in a subquery in SELECT field list about t2_type

Comment: I strongly recommend *always* fully qualifying all column references with `table_name.column_name`.  Your `WHERE` clause is a headache without fully qualifying the references.

Comment: @MatBailie Are you saying that aliases are bad?

Comment: @MatBailie Sorry, I update a query

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Check his edit.   Before it I couldn't see where `t2_date` came from, after the edit it was clear *(er)*, so I changed my comment.  I made no mention of aliases, I mentioned only that there was a field with no obvious source, and that to avoid that ambiguity, fully qualified references should be used.  As far as I'm concerned, for this topic, `alias.column` is equivalent to `table.column`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is a bit of a hack, using `substring_index()`/`group_concat()`:

```
SELECT t1.t1_id, t1.t1.Company, t1.t1_some_field, last_t2.t2_type 
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2
     (SELECT MAX(t2_date) AS Last_Date, company, t2_t1_id,
             SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t2.t2_type ORDER BY t2.t2_date DESC), ',', 1) as last_t2_type
      FROM t2
      GROUP BY company, t2_t1_id
     ) last_t2
     ON t1.company = last_t2.company AND t1_id = last_t2.t2_t1_id;
```

Another method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*,
       (select t2.t2_type
        from t2
        where t1.company = t2.company and t1.t1_id = t2.t2_t1_id
        order by t2.t2_date desc
        limit 1
       ) as t2_type
from t1;
```

With an index on `t2(company, t2_t1_id, date)`, this may have the best performance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1_id, t1.Company t1_some_field, 
    (SELECT t2_type 
    FROM t2
    WHERE t2.t2_t1_id = t1.id
    AND t1.company = t2.company
    AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 'NEXT'
        FROM t2 t2next
        WHERE t2.t2_t1_id = t2next.t2_t1_id
        AND t2.company = t2next.company
        AND t2.t2_date > t2next.t2_date)
    )
FROM t1
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be rewritten as follows, however, it will probably lead to the same query plan as in your case

```
SELECT t1_id, t1.Company  t1_some_field, t2_type 
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t2
ON t1.company = t2.company 
AND t1_id = t2.t2_t1_id
WHERE t2.t2_date =
    (
        SELECT MAX(t2_date) 
        FROM t2
        WHERE t1.company = t2.company AND 
              t1.t1_id = t2.t2_t1_id
        GROUP BY company, t2_t1_id
    )
```

If you have MySQL supporting window functions (since version 8.0.0) then there is another way using `row_number`, but I recommend using your solution.